# Why reduce behaves differently from hand-written chain methods?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I think `Rx.Observable.prototype.reduce` is like `Array.prototype.reduce` so I write code like that way

```
        function fn(prev, num){
            return Rx.Observable.of(prev+num);
        }

        fn(1, 1).switchMap(res =>fn(res, 2))
                .switchMap(res =>fn(res, 3))
                .subscribe(x=>console.log(x));

        // 7 



        Rx.Observable.from([2,3]).reduce(
            (prev, cur) =>prev.switchMap(res => fn(res, cur)),
            fn(1, 1)
        ).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))

        // SwitchObservable {source: FlatMapObservable}
```

I wonder why I cannot use scan in this way?  How could I use Operators in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your accumulator is an Observable. You can get your value by calling switchMap one more time:

```
Rx.Observable.from([2,3]).scan(
    (prev, cur) =>prev.switchMap(res => fn(res, cur)),
    fn(1, 1)
).last().switchMap(x => x).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

**After editing**

```
Rx.Observable.from([2,3]).reduce(
    (prev, cur) =>prev.switchMap(res => fn(res, cur)),
    fn(1, 1)
).switchMap(x => x).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```